# Не воспроизводяться звуки (SoundPool: Error creating AudioTrack)

Tags: android

Инициализирую аудио

```
    SoundPool sp;
    int error_sound;
    int del_sound;
    int level_complete_sound;
    int level_complete_123;



    // Аудио
    sp = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

    error_sound = sp.load(this, R.raw.error_sound, 1);
    del_sound = sp.load(this, R.raw.del_sound, 1);
    level_complete_sound = sp.load(this, R.raw.level_complete_sound, 1);
    level_complete_123 = sp.load(this, R.raw.level_complete_123, 1);
```

а затем использую многократно
то один то другой звук при нажатии

```
sp.play(error_sound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
```

Все работает, но изредка, особенно при перезапуске activity звуки работают через один, и возникает ошибка

```
E/AudioMixer: AudioMixer::getTrackName out of available tracks
E/AudioFlinger: no more track names available
E/AudioFlinger: createTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
E/AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
E/SoundPool: Error creating AudioTrack
```

Файлы аудио небольшого размера и длительности, порядка 3-6 секунд.
Сама ошибка, как я понимаю указывает на то что трек не может загрузится из-за нехватки памяти. Но я не понимаю что именно я делаю не так.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.
Ошибка указывает на то что превышен лимит на загрузку треков. Лимит установлен на всю систему и равен если не ошибаюсь `32`. При перезапуске `activity` звуки каждый раз загружаются, тем самым подводя нас ближе к лимиту в `32` трека. Для того что бы это исключить необходимо очищать `SoundPool`.

При инициализации указываем:

```
SoundPool sp = null;
```

И очищаем при перезапуске:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Очищаем SoundPool
        if (sp != null) {
            sp.release();
            sp = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Подгружаем аудио при возобновлении
        if (sp == null) {
            sp = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
            error_sound = sp.load(this, R.raw.error_sound, 1);
            del_sound = sp.load(this, R.raw.del_sound, 1);
            level_complete_sound = sp.load(this, R.raw.level_complete_sound, 1);
            level_complete_123 = sp.load(this, R.raw.level_complete_123, 1);
        }
    }
```